# Decode &#55357; to real character

Tags: xml, unicode

when I read data from Stream API of twitter and then write to xmlfile.

But some special character like `&#55357;` will cause error (I mean when I open that xmlfile in Chrome, Chrome said that there was an error at that character!)

I want to convert that encoded sequence (`&#55357;`) into real character (�) before writing to xmlfile!

How to implement this?

-------------ADDED--------------

This is the XMLFile content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<text>@carlyraejepsen would be a dream if you follow me, please follow me?, I love you so much you're my inspiration</text>
<text>someone please bring me a caramel apple and a mocha from black cat. i'll love you forever</text>
<text>“@G_MartinFlyKick: Marry me Juliet.I love you and that's all I really know.”&#55357;&#56834;&#55357;&#56834;&#55357;&#56834;&#55357;&#56834;&#55357;&#56834;</text>
<text>"I need to see a picture of him cuz Im trying to imagine you guys making love and all I see is u climbing on top of a big question mark"lmao</text>
<text>@District3music hi, I LOVE YOU follow me please? &amp;lt;3 xx 23</text>
<text>RT @syardley_: So appreciative of my family and people I love, wouldn't be where I am without them. #thankful</text>
<text>#DISTRICT3HALLOWEENFOLLOWSPREE #DISTRICT3HALLOWEENFOLLOWSPREE #3EEKERFROMTHENETHERLANDS love you! Please follow ? @District3music x42</text>
<text>Arguably my favorite electronic music producer @Kluteuk is coming back to Toronto on Dec 22nd. So stoked. Guy has made so many tunes I LOVE.</text>
<text>The stakes are high, the water's rough, but this love is ours.</text>
<text>@NiallOfficial Answer me, I love you very much. Venezuela loves. jhgj</text>
<text>Love this shit http://t.co/qSP79NKx</text>
</root>
```

And here is error from Chrome:

```
This page contains the following errors:

error on line 5 at column 91: xmlParseCharRef: invalid xmlChar value 55357
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.
```

Comment: What language/framework are you using? .NET? C? 6502 assembler?

Comment: What does the error say? Please show us the XML.

Comment: I added some more details @SLaks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4237625/removing-invalid-xml-characters-from-a-string-in-java/45223107#45223107

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The character reference `&#55357;` denotes a surrogate code point (U+D83D), so it would be wrong to try to convert it to a character. It is not a character, not even half a character.

You need to track back to the point where the reference was generated. The reason might be a character encoding confusion. In UTF-16, surrogate code units may appear but must be handled in pairs when the data is interpreted as characters and e.g. converted to another encoding or turned to character references.

Comment: I retrieve data from this link: https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json?delimited=length&track=love, so, how encoding confusion occur?

Comment: @Songokute, hard to tell, because the page prompts for a user name and password.

Comment: Judging by the XMLFile content, it seems that the data contains characters like U+1F602 “”, which means that it occupies two code units in UTF-16. Apparently the original data is UTF-16 and should first be converted to UTF-8.

Comment: Sorry for replying late! But you can use your twitter account to login! (Because this is twitter stream API). And, do you mean that I should change encode of XMLFile from UTF-8 to UTF-16?

Comment: Yea, I did it, thanks @Korpela, I set encoding to UTF-16 for xmlObject before writing it down :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use regular expressions to replace it after the server response.
simple example in python:

```
import re 
pattern = re.compile(r'&#')
new_content = pattern.sub(' ', SERVER_RESPONSE)
```