# Escape HTML entities that aren't XML

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, xml-parsing, html-entities

I'm parsing an XML file that was produced by an SMS backup app, but some things are escaped with HTML entities. I'm using `xml.etree.ElementTree`, but it complains with `xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: reference to invalid character number: line 29, column 308`, which lines up with `&#55357;&#56841;&#10;` in the XML file. I know that I can use BeautifulSoup. In fact, I already have a working program that uses it, but I'm trying to rewrite it so that I can speed it up. A sample tag is here:

```
<sms protocol="0" address="1012223434" date="1548857971596" type="1" subject="null" body="... by the time you want a ride. &#55357;&#56841;&#10;" toa="null" sc_toa="null" service_center="null" read="1" status="-1" locked="0" date_sent="0" readable_date="Jan 30, 2019 9:19:31 AM" contact_name="Mom" />
```

I've used `iterparse` on the data in the interest of not consuming too much memory, but I've also tried just using `parse` and clearing every element when I'm done so that I can have better control, but I haven't actually been able to figure out this one part. If I use `html.unescape`, it unescapes too much, and then I get `xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 27, column 175`, which is where there was a `&apos;` before it was unescaped. If I try to put `xml.sax.saxutils.escape` on top of the unescaped HTML, then that of course also escapes everything else that's actually supposed to be part of the XML.

How can I unescape the HTML entities without going too far and unescaping all the XML entities?

Answer (score 0):

### XML Allowed Characters

[Per the W3C XML Recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#charsets)

> ```
> [2] Char ::= #x9 | #xA | #xD | [#x20-#xD7FF] | [#xE000-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#x10FFFF]
> ```

**Notation**

- `&#`d`;` notation means that *d* is a **decimal** representation of the character's code point.
- `&#x`d`;` notation means that *d* is a **hexadecimal** representation of the character's code point.

### Error Analysis

- `&#55357;` is `&#xD83D;`, which is not a legal character in XML.
- `&#56841;` is `&#xDE09;`, which is also not a legal character in XML.

Therefore, your opening statement,

> I'm parsing an XML file

is incorrect and you ***cannot use a conformant XML parser to parse this data***.  Instead, you're relegated to using techniques at [How to parse invalid (bad / not well-formed) XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44765194/290085)

The #1 recommendation there is to fix the problem at the origin.  (Hint: In UTF-**16**, [`55,357 56,842`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f609/index.htm) is , so consider encoding issues.)  If fixing the origin is not possible, the above link suggests numerous other alternatives for dealing with bad "XML" in many different programming languages, including Python.

### See also

- [Decode &#55357; to real character](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13165408/290085)
- [Emoji character sequence &#55357;&#56391; breaks old XML process](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53038978/290085)

Answer (score 0):

This library can handle HTML and XML, with strong fault tolerance

```
from simplified_scrapy.simplified_doc import SimplifiedDoc
html='''<sms protocol="0" address="1012223434" date="1548857971596" type="1" subject="null" body="... by the time you want a ride. &#55357;&#56841;&#10;" toa="null" sc_toa="null" service_center="null" read="1" status="-1" locked="0" date_sent="0" readable_date="Jan 30, 2019 9:19:31 AM" contact_name="Mom" />'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html).getElementByTag('sms')
print (doc)
```

Result:

```
{'tag': 'sms', 'protocol': '0', 'address': '1012223434', 'date': '1548857971596', 'type': '1', 'subject': 'null', 'body': '... by the time you want a ride. &#55357;&#56841;&#10;', 'toa': 'null', 'sc_toa': 'null', 'service_center': 'null', 'read': '1', 'status': '-1', 'locked': '0', 'date_sent': '0', 'readable_date': 'Jan 30, 2019 9:19:31 AM', 'contact_name': 'Mom'}
```

You can get the examples of SimplifiedDoc [here](https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/tree/master/doc_examples)