# Can Apache Wink ignore unprintable xml characters?

Tags: xml, jaxb, control-characters, apache-wink

My application supports REST API using Wink and a JAXB provider built in to the JDK (1.6).
Sometimes I receive PUT requests that contain control characters.

As far as my application is concerned, the control characters constitute a valid and meaningful input.
However, the application throws the notorious exception saying that it cannot digest these characters:

```
Message: An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x13) was found in the element content of the document.]
at org.apache.wink.common.internal.providers.entity.xml.JAXBXmlProvider.readFrom(JAXBXmlProvider.java:107)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.registry.ServerInjectableFactory$EntityParam.getValue(ServerInjectableFactory.java:190)
at org.apache.wink.common.internal.registry.InjectableFactory.instantiate(InjectableFactory.java:67)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.CreateInvocationParametersHandler.handleRequest
```

There is probably no way to tell the JAXB provider to ignore these characters (since at some point I will have to parse the Xml, and illegal is illegal..).
How can I make this work? Is there a way to instruct the Rest client to escape these characters before sending them?

Comment: Control characters are [not allowed in XML](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#charsets) so your data is not XML. The trouble with trying to define _it is like X except for Y_ is that it would be difficult to define an API where Y can be whatever the individual thinks it should be. It is unlikely JAXB will accommodate you. You could use a filter to strip the illegal characters if that is acceptable; otherwise you will have to encode or escape the data in legal character data (e.g. with Base64.)

Comment: @McDowell please post as answer and I will accept. Thanks.

Comment: @McDowell will it work in JSon?

Comment: Alas, no - control characters cannot be encoded in JSON strings as per [the specification](http://www.json.org/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Control characters are [not allowed in XML](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#charsets) so your data is not XML. The trouble with *it is like X except for Y* is that it would be difficult to define an API where Y can be whatever the individual thinks it should be. It is unlikely JAXB will accommodate you. You could use a filter to strip the illegal characters if that is acceptable; otherwise you will have to encode or escape the data in legal character data (e.g. with [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).)

Comment: I will write a filter. Given the encoding and the ServletInputStream, is there an easy way to determine whether the char I just read is a control character?

Comment: You will need to determine the document encoding from the [declaration](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xml-20040204/#NT-XMLDecl) (see also [appendix F](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xml-20040204/#sec-guessing)) and decode it to determine if the [code point](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#codePointAt%28char%5B%5D%2C%20int%29) is supported. You can test against the [character ranges](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#charsets) in the XML spec. Then provide your own stream to the forward chain.

Comment: Say I determined that the Encoding is UTF8. I see that the Character class contains a method isISOControl, that has a version that inputs a Unicode codepoint. Will it work or do I need another conversion?

Comment: `Character.isISOControl('\n');` evaluates to true, so this isn't exactly what you want. This question has been asked before - see [removing invalid XML characters from a string in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4237625) for example. The problem of filtering invalid character ranges from XML-like data in a servlet filter probably deserves its own question (though don't be surprised if the answerers question why you would send invalid data to such a service instead of using a more appropriate format.)

Answer (score 2):

The characters in question are not "unprintable XML characters". They are unprintable non-XML characters.