How to manage \uFFFF character with Jackson (XML)?
I've just come across what I believe is a weird behaviour in Jackson XML (de)serialization.
The character \uFFFF is accepted when serializing but leads to an error when deserialized.
XmlMapper xml = new XmlMapper();

String xmlString = xml.writeValueAsString("Some valid string but containing the \uFFFF character");
System.out.println(xmlString);
// <String>Some valid string but containing the &#xffff; character</String>

String deser = xml.readValue(xmlString, String.class);
System.out.println(deser);
// java.lang.RuntimeException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Illegal character entity: expansion character (code 0xffff
// at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,53]
// at [Source: (StringReader); line: 1, column: 54]

What is the proper way of handling this? How to tell Jackson to not write this character if it doesn't support reading it back?
EDIT: I still want a "plain string" as XML output (no hexa/base64 encoding). I don't need to preserve this character. Just removing/ignoring it is fine.
(Jackson version: 2.17.1)

U+FFFF is the undefined character. Why are you serialising it in the first place?

I don't own the input data. I mean I can remove it obviously but I wonder why Jackson let me serialize it in the first place then? And I guess there are other cases that I don't know yet of similar type of characters.

The correct way to handle this is to encode (effectively) binary data containing undefined Unicode characters in hex or base64 or something before embedding it in a serialization.  Note that valid XML should not contain U+FFFE or U+FFFF; see https://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#charsets.

To clarify: I don't want to preserve the character. On the contrary, I'm looking for the best way to not write it / ignore it.

Well ... the best way to not write it would be to validate the string or whatever that could contain these invalid characters before you serialize the data.  If you have gotten to the point of serializing, it is too late.

I still find it strange that Jackson let me write invalid XML but if it's the only way, I'll validate the string first then. Thanks :)

Could this FFFF character be coming due to having read the string using the wrong encoding?

It is indeed possible @k314159. I'm in some kind of generic processing code. And, unfortunately, the client can send whatever crapy data not honoring the encoding we're supposed to accept. I get what you're all saying: there must be some validation done before it reaches the XML serialization, totally agree with that :)

GIGO. You can prevent GI maybe with something like s = s.codePoints().filter(Character::isDefined).mapToObj(Character::toString).collect(Collectors.joining()); But as already said, it looks like the GI has come from faulty en/decoding further back

Voting to reopen. Unicode Technical Corrigendum #9 states that a non-character can in fact be used for internal purposes in a valid Unicode string. The suggestions given in the comments so far are therefore misleading.

To clarify, '\uFFFF" is a valid Unicode code point and is allowed to appear in a String (for internal uses), but is not a valid character in an XML document. Since this API presumably doesn't say to the client that their strings must only contain characters that are valid in XML documents, your application chooses to convert the string to XML as an implementation detail and therefore must do whatever is necessary to preserve all characters when converting to XML and back.

For the record, I used https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4237625/removing-invalid-xml-characters-from-a-string-in-java to remove some chars before serializing.
